# Issue in running pod install when using flutter_opencv plugin

Tags: ios, flutter, opencv, cocoapods

I am trying to build a flutter application using flutter opencv plugin but when I try to build it for the iOS device, I run into this error while running pod install -

Analyzing dependencies

```
Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `opencv` from `.symlinks/plugins/opencv/ios`
[!] No podspec found for `opencv` in `.symlinks/plugins/opencv/ios`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:989:in `fetch_external_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:968:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:966:in `fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile.
See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Exception: Error running pod install

How can resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Even if my answer is late, I had the same problem and finally found the answer. On Dart pub the plugin is tagged as compatible with iOS. However, on the project description it states:

> **Notes**
> iOS not supported currently - I do not own a Mac, so deploying for iOS will be a little slow.

So I guess you will have to implement it yourself.